No output from Invoke-SSHCommand from module Posh-SSH inside eventhandler Powershell GUI
I have a problem were I am not getting an output from Invoke-SSHCommand inside a .Add_SelectedIndexChanged. I need this output to check if a tmux session is running on my linux machine.
#executes commands on server via SSH-posh
$Creds = Get-Credential
$global:Session = New-SSHSession -ComputerName myip -Credential $Creds -AcceptKey
$ServerAmount = Invoke-SSHCommand -SSHSession $global:Session -Command "ls /mnt/server"


#This is giving me a output
$ActiveServer = Invoke-SSHCommand -SSHSession $global:Session -Command "tmux ls"
$ActiveServer.Output 



#Adds all the server directories to combobox
foreach ($server in $ServerAmount.Output){
    if ($server -ne "lost+found"){
        $ddlServer.Items.Add($server)
    }     
}

#On Selected Item changed do this: 
$ddlServer.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({
    

    $txbOutput.Text = ""
    $SelectedServer = $ddlServer.SelectedItem
    $txbOutput.AppendText($SelectedServer)

    #Execute tmux ls to see what servers are running
    

    #this is not giving me any output
    $ActiveServer = Invoke-SSHCommand -SSHSession $global:Session -Command "tmux ls"
    $ActiveServer.Output
    

    if ($SelectedServer -match $ActiveServer.Output) {
        $txbOutput.AppendText("Server Status: Up")
    }

    else {
        $txbOutput.AppendText("Server Status: Down")
    }
})

I have tried makning everything inside $ddlServer.Add_SelectedIndexChanged into a function and then running inside a $ddlServer.Add_SelectedIndexChanged. That makes no diffrence. I dont think it can be any permission/connection issue since it works otherwise and I have made sure that there is an actual output from "tmux ls". I have tried switching the event handler to a diffrent one, a ".Add_Click", that doesnt seem to work either.

Try changing From : $ActiveServer.Output To : $ActiveServer | Format-List

@jdweng thanks for suggestion, but that didnt work :(

I have no clue what made it work but this works:
# Execute commands or perform operations over SSH
$output = Invoke-SSHCommand -SessionId $global:Session.SessionId -Command "tmux ls"



# Extract only the server name
$ActiveServer = ""
$output.Output | ForEach-Object {
    $serverName = $_ -split ':', 2   # Split the line at the colon and take the first part
    $ActiveServer += $serverName[0] + "`r`n"  # Append the extracted server name along with a newline character
}

